# Change variable value on window width change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I am fairly new to **jQuery/javascript** and I have a quick question, probably very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to change a variable value when the window width has changed. The reason I'm doing it with jQuery is that I can't alter the width or height via css.

**This is my code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jwheight = 390,
    windowSize = $(window).width();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if (windowSize < 992) {
            jwheight = 39;
        }
    })

player.initialize(800, jwheight, "player", "http://www.website.com", "http://www.website.com/static/images/logo.png", true);

</script>
```

So I want to change the height **(jwheight)** when the window width is smaller than 992px.

All help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Make the if `if ($(window).width() < 992)`

Comment: you have to re-calculate the window width inside the function. The initial width calculated was initialy before any window re-size. That is the point

Comment: Note that changing the variable `jwheight` doesn't change the `player` object.

Comment: @Guffa how would I go about changing the player object? I need that height to change

Comment: @KD1: Use the new variable value to call the `resize` method of the player.

Answer (score 3):

your `windowSize` is outside the resize function, so it will always have the same value. You should use the width inside the function as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jwheight = 390;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 992) {
            jwheight = 39;
        }
    })

    player.initialize(800, jwheight, "player", "http://www.website.com", "http://www.website.com/static/images/logo.png", true);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanx @taxicala I'll try this out

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$(window).width()` value inside the `resize` event, and resize the player depending on the result.

You would want to calculate the height depending on the width, then compare that to the current height so that you don't call `player.resize` when there isn't actually a size change:

```
var jwheight = 390;

$(window).resize(function(){
  var newHeight = $(window).width() < 992 ? 39 : 390;
  if (newHeight != jwheight) {
    jwheight = newHeight;
    player.resize(800, jwheight);
  }
})

player.initialize(800, jwheight, "player", "http://www.website.com", "http://www.website.com/static/images/logo.png", true);
```